# How to parse specific parts from table using PHP and Simple HTML Dom

Tags: php, parsing, simple-html-dom

I have managed to parse a table from some website, but I only need some elements:

```
include('simple_html_dom.php'); 
$html = file_get_html($kako);
foreach($html->find('table') as $e)
  echo $e->innertext . '<br>';
$html->clear();
unset($html);
```

For this input:

```
<tr>
  <td style="word-wrap: break-word;">
    <a href="/info/......us" title="......">Title</a> 
    <img alt="Verified" Title="Verified and marked" src="/images/verified.png" width="20" height="20">
    <br>
    <a href="/file/........." rel="nofollow">
    <img alt="........" Title="........." src="......" width="16" height="16"></a>
    <a href="magnet:?xt=urn:btih:.......A1337" rel="nofollow">
    <img  alt="Download ..... using magnet link" Title="Dow.....ing magnet link" src="/images/magnet.svg" width="16" height="16"></a> 
    Uploaded 5 days ago Size 1.6 GB</td><td class="is-hidden-touch" >1.6 GB
  </td>
  <td class="is-hidden-touch" style="text-align: center;" >5</td>
  <td class="is-hidden-touch" style="text-align: center;">5 days ago</td><td style="text-align: center;">6627</td><td style="text-align: center;">2445</td>
</tr>
```

I need title, magnet link (`<a href="magnet:?>`) and the text "Uploaded 5 days ago....".

Is that possible? I have searched all manuals and could't find anything.

Comment: What is file_get_html() and what does find() deliver?

Comment: @Gerriet, It is a function of Simple HTML DOM it is an open source HTML DOM parser written for PHP5+ which lets users easily manipulate HTML.

Comment: Which Title do you need here?

Comment: @vaha, Have you got a solution?

Answer (score 0):

```
foreach($html->find('a') as $element){
        if (strpos($element->href, 'magnet:') !== false){
            $hrf = $element->href;
        }
    }
    foreach($html->find('img') as $ele){
        if(strpos($ele->title, 'magnet link') !== false){
            $title = $ele->title;
        }
    }
    foreach($html->find('td') as $eletd){
        if(strpos($eletd->text,'Uploaded') !== false){
            $text = $eletd->text;
        }
    }
```

I have customized code according to your HTML. Hope this works for you!

Comment: Thank you so much for helping, i just saw answer, let me try it

Comment: Nothing happend, here is my web site vaha  net / film / logan and there is in links section torrent part. that i got when i use my code from first post.

Comment: As you will see, it's not beautiful table. All i want is magnet Title, magnet link, and Size Files Added Seeds Peers info.